# implementing catching exceptions when assertions failed in readyapi rest calls in scriptassetrion groovy file

Tags: exception, groovy, ready-api

i am relatively new to readyapi and trying to catch assertion failures then call other test steps when assertion failed rather than test execution exits when assertion failed. I am using script assertion , any help will be greatly appreciated